# Solr search by sentence similarity

Tags: solr, lucene

I have a text document indexed in Solr.  I want Solr search to first show the text files that have a similar sentence, and then to show files that have similar words.

So far, I have used this query:

```
"This is a sample text" OR This is a sample text
```

But then, when searching "This a sample text", for example, it will search for any document that contains ("this", "a", "sample" and "text"). Is there any method in Solr for the search to first provide results with similar sentences and then words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [phrase query with slop](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_2_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Proximity_Searches) (or proximity search) sounds like what you are looking for.

Such as:

```
"This a sample text"~3 this a sample text
```